# how to prove the limit of the sequences exist?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

suppose ${x_n}$ is a numerical sequence such that $$0<x_{n+m}\leq x_n+x_m$$ for all $n$ and $m\in \mathbb{N}$ and $x_1>0$. Prove that  $lim_{n\rightarrow \infty }\frac{x_n}{n}$ exists.

Comment: I don't know how to prove the limit exists, I only know that $\frac{x_n}{n}$ has a upper bound $x_1$